# How to remotely log out from Google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Can I log out from Google Chrome in a remote PC where I signed in. I logged in the library PC on my Google Chrome but forgot to log out.

How can I log out from the library PC from home?

Comment: If I change my google password, will that log me out of chrome?

Comment: @metal gear solid. Why don't you go back over some of your old questions and set them to answered (where possible?) 44% is very low.

Comment: Note that logging out (remotely) doesn't remove any saved/synced passwords or browsing history. It just means people have to browse to the chrome profile directory to get at your data. This is why the local sign-out button has a checkmark for clearing data.

Comment: @jiggunjer I'm not sure when Google added it (or if it was always an option), but the default setting now is for saved passwords to be encrypted with your account username and password.  In this case I think any saved password data will be unusable if the account is logged out even if it is still technically present on a device.

Answer (score 31):

Very easy, you must go to [Security settings](https://www.google.com/settings/security?ref=home), then you just change your password and this will log all computers out of anything to do with your Google chrome account and it also stops that computer logging back in if the password was saved on that computer, until you get back to that computer station again.

Comment: I guess this is the best option, which lets you keep your chrome data. But, does this remove the data from the remote chrome?

Comment: @RahulThakur No, this will not remove existing data.

Comment: does this solution prevent someone using the other device from accessing the chrome profile that is synced with google, or will they still be able to switch to that profile?

Answer (score 11):

To remotely log out of Chrome's browser sync, you can revoke access to Google Chrome in your [account permissions settings](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions). This will prevent someone else from using that browser to delete your bookmarks, for example, but **it won't clear bookmarks, cookies, or saved passwords** from that browser. (Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like any of the other options here guarantee that either.)

Answer (score 11):

Might be very old but there is a new way to do that

https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity

You can check all your recently connected devices and you can also remove devices here.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This link shows which devices I am logged into Chrome on but no longer seems to provide a way to log out an individual device. Instead the 'Secure your account' link gives you the option of changing your Google password as top answers suggests. However this did still solve my problem which was I wanted to find out what unknown device I was still logged in on.

Comment: Late to the Party, but as of this date, going to your main Google account page and clicking on Security Checkup has a tab with signed in devices and the facility to log out anything you need to.

Answer (score 8):

Note, that this would log you out of all your Chrome browsers in all PCs, and you may loose your syncing data.

Go to [Google Accounts dashboard](https://www.google.com/dashboard/). Scroll down to `Chrome sync` and then click on `Stop sync and delete data from Google`.

Answer (score 7):

If you are worried about someone accessing your email, log into your gmail, scroll to the bottom of the screen, off to the right there will be a line saying "Last account activity X time ago" Under that is a link to details. Click the link, and you will be presented with recent activity for your account. At the top there will be a link to log out all sessions, except the one you are on. This will prevent anyone from accessing your email, except from your current session. Please refer to attached photo[image]

Comment: Does this sign out from chrome also? The question was for chrome and not gmail. Has anyone tested this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean, you wish to log out of sites within Google Chrome.

Only a few sites currently allow you to remotely sign out, such as:

- [Gmail](http://gmailblog.blogspot.in/2008/07/remote-sign-out-and-info-to-help-you.html)
- [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/forget-to-log-out-help-is-on-the-way/425136200765)
- [Zoho](http://blogs.zoho.com/general/remote-sign-out-in-zoho.html)

[Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp) is a new Chrome extension that lets you remotely control a computer from your browser. However, it requires that you have [entered a one-time authentication code on the second computer (library PC) prior to first usage](http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2011/10/chrome-remote-desktop.html).

Comment: Well, Chrome itself can be signed into Google's Sync service.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to log out of all devices without having to change your password is to temporarily turn on 2-step verification. This will give you the ability to "revoke access" from all devices.

Go to your google account and log in.
https://myaccount.google.com/
Under Sign in and security, scroll down and select "2 step verification"
Follow the steps to setup up 2 step verification. At the last step you will have the option to "revoke access" from all devices.
After access is revoked, you can turn off 2 step verification.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to Google Dashboard

You can find Google Sync Option. Beside to it you can find "Stop sync and delete data from google"

By doing this you can log out of the Google Chrome. But this will affect the Sync between your setting.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way*, since I have to RMA a laptop but can't boot to clean HDD.

Go to https://myaccount.google.com/

From there, on this main dashboard, there are few big cards, in my case there are 4, one of them says something along the lines of `Security Checkup`

It actually changes title, if you haven't been there in a while it will say something like `Perform Security Checkup` or just simply `We keep your account protected`

Basically make sure to click that big card, **not** in the left hand menu, you will be greeted with following menu

```
Security Checkup

Your devices
XX signed-in devices

Recent security events
XX recent event

Sign-in & recovery
XX verification methods

Third-party access
XX app with access to your data

Gmail settings
XX sensitive setting
```

From this menu if you expand devices you will have for each a small vertical three dots menu with option to logout that particular device.

Do notice that going to your devices from left hand menu does not offer this option!

** please notice that google changes things often, this works as of July 2019, but there is no guarantee it will work at later date*

Answer (score -1):

If you've forgotten to sign out of Chrome on another computer, you can sign out of your other sessions by going to the bottom right corner of Gmail, clicking Details, and then Sign out all other sessions.

Comment: The question is about *Chrome*, not *Gmail*. Flagging as "not an answer" as it does not attempt to address the question as written.

Comment: Seems like an appropriate answer, but it has been asked above if this actually works. No confirmation yet.

Comment: For example, this site suggests this works: http://mobile.geek.com/android/13596-geek-101-how-to-sign-out-of-chrome-on-all-devices

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/a/541882/573485) answer already says the same thing, but in a more detailed way.